# Der Hund bellt, aber die Krähe ...?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Ich suche nach der Benennung der **Lautäußerungen von Krähen** (wenn sie rufen, wie es Ornithologen vermutlich nennen würden). Das naheliegende *Krähen* ist leider schon durch die Hähne besetzt, und mit den nächsten Verwandten der Krähe hat man es leichter:

- Elstern schackern.
- Eichelhäher rätschen.
- Raben krächzen (wirklich, oder steht das Wort nur abwertend für die »hässliche Stimme«?)

Gibt es eine eigene Bezeichnung oder muss man sich mit dem Wort *krächzen* begnügen?

Comment: Habe noch nie von schackern und rätschen gehört - ist das vielleicht waidmännisch?

Comment: *rätschen* mit *sch* - könnte weidmännisch sein, ich habe es aus Büchern über diese Vögel.

Comment: Frage: Wie verlässlich ist an dieser Stelle [de.wiktionary.org](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/krähen)? Dort wird *krähen* als Verb für den Hahn **und** die Krähe geführt. Im Gegensatz dazu steht im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kraehen) nur der Hahn als zugehöriges Tier. Btw, wenn man mal auf Google nach ["Die Krähe krähte"](http://is.gd/G6rjfv) sucht, so findet man einige alte Bücher, die diese beiden Wörter zusammen nutzen

Comment: @nixda Ich habe gestern den [Kluge](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_deutschen_Sprache) gewältzt und dort steht, dass *krähen* und *krächzen* gleichermaßen mit *Krähe* (*Krächzerin*) verwandt sind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Krächzen ist das richtige Wort für diesen Laut (Krähe - krächzen - die beiden Wörter sind sogar vom Schreibbild her verwandt).

Die Ableitung zu der Bedeutung "mit unschöner Stimme sprechen" kam später, wenn jemand wie eine Krähe klang, dann krächzte er.

Ähnlich: heulen für weinen, winseln für betteln etc.

Comment: Ich hatte das befürchtet (+1: kannst du ja nichts dafür). Im übrigen *singen* diese Vögel mitunter sogar - schon mal gehört?

Comment: Was hast du befürchtet? Ich verstehe diesen Kommentar nicht, tut mir leid. Setzt du dich für das Image der Krähen ein?

Comment: Randnotiz zum "Trost": Krähen sind Singvögel...

Comment: Von welchen Tieren stammt den Heulen und Winseln ab?

Comment: Wölfe heulen, Hundebabys winseln. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heulen http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/winseln

Comment: @Stephie ja, war mir bekannt.

Comment: @BarthZalewski ok, war etwas schwülstig formuliert, ich hatte gehofft, jemand wüsste ein unvorbelasteteres Wort.

Comment: @Wolf jetzt verstehe ich

Answer (score 2):

**Krähen krähen.**

Zitat aus dem Eintrag zum Verb [»krähen« auf Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kr%C3%A4hen)

> Bedeutungen:
>    [**1**] den typischen Tierlaut einer Krähe machen
>    [**2**] den typischen Tierlaut eines Hahnes machen
>
> Beispiele:
>    [**1**] Die Krähe kräht.
>    [**2**] Der Hahn kräht auf dem Mist.

Andere Quelle: DUDEN - Das Herkunfswörterbuch (3. Auflage) Seite 448:

> **Krähe:** Die Krähe ist nach ihrem heiseren Geschrei als »Krächzerin« benannt. *[Die an dieser Stelle aufgezählten Formen]* gehören zu der unter *krähen* behandelten Lautnachahmung.

Im gleich drunter stehenden Eintrag zum Verb *krähen* steht, dass das Wort aus der Nachahmung eines Lautes entstanden ist, uns dass neben dem englischen »crow« und den deutschen Wörtern »krähen« und »Krähe« auch »Kranich«, »krachen«, »krächzen«, »kreischen« und »kreißen« derselben lautmalerischen Wurzel entstammen.

Alternativ kann man auch sagen:

**Krähen krächzen.**

*Krähen* und *krächzen* sind, wie oben gezeigt, beide aus dem Versuch entstanden den entsprechenden Laut nachzuahmen.

Comment: Danke für die Mühe! Welche Antwort nun die akzeptablere ist, sollte die Zeit helfen zu entscheiden :)