# Warum krähen Hähne - und Krähen nicht?

Tags: etymology

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/der-hund-bellt-aber-die-kr%C3%A4he) wird gefragt, wie die Lautäußerung der Krähen lautet - (mit der Antwort *krächzen*, die dort gegeben wurde, bin ich übrigens nicht einig - Krähen *rufen* oder *schreien*. *krächzen* ist meiner Meinung nach für Raben reserviert.)

- Hähne krähen
- Raben krächzen
- Krähen rufen oder schreien

Wieso hat sich der Hahn die Lautäußerung der Krähe geschnappt, der Rabe in anderer Form auch und für die arme Krähe ist nichts übrig geblieben? Sind Verb und Substantiv überhaupt verwandt oder nur lautähnlich?

Natürlich ist es nicht unbedingt so, dass Verben zum Hauptwort passen müssen - Hunde *hunden* ja schließlich auch nicht, sondern bellen. Aber immerhin darf das Wiesel *wieseln* und die Schlange *sich schlängeln*.

Ein Versuch der Klarstellung: Ich gehe von meinem umgangssprachlichen (und damit nicht notwendigerweise dem ornithologischen) Sprachgebrauch und damit dem Unterschied zwischen Rabe und Krähe aus - Der meint mit einem Raben sowas wie einen *[Kolkraben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolkrabe)* und mit einer Krähe eine *[Saatkrähe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saatkr%C3%A4he)*. Grade diese zwei Vögel unterscheiden sich erheblich in ihren Möglichkeiten der Lautäußerung.

Und noch als Anmerkung ein kurzer Ausflug ins Englische, dort *krähen* ("to crow") *roosters* und *cocks* erstaunlicherweise auch, aber Krähen *stoßen einen heiseren Schrei aus* ("to caw").

Comment: Das Wort "Krähe" ist ja etymologisch aus dem krähenden Laut erstanden, also onomatopoetisch, also nicht umgekehrt! D.h. es ist anders herum und sie müssen einmal schon gekräht haben, jetzt aber nicht mehr.

Comment: »Raben und Krähen« ist eine Tiergattung innerhalb der Familie der Rabenvögel. Daher sind alle Krähen Rabenvögel! Zu sagen »Nur Raben  krächzen, Krähen krächzen nicht« ist so sinnvoll wie zu sagen »Nur Bayern trinken Bier, Münchner trinken keines«. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raben_und_Krähen

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, in dem Artikel, den Du angibst, steht aber auch, dass die größeren Raben und die kleineren Krähen heißen. Und in der Alltagssprache gibt es keine Rabenvögel. Das schreibe ich jetzt nicht, um zu widersprechen, sondern weil ich Raben interessant finde, seit ich ein Buch von Heinrich über sie gelesen habe.

Comment: @Beta Ist das so?

Comment: @CarstenS Aber umgangssprachlich werden die Rabenvögel doch als Raben bezeichnet. Den genauen Unterschied zwischen Raben und Krähen kennen nur die wenigsten. Für die meisten sind das "Raben" (im Sinne von "Rabenvögel"), obwohl es eigentlich z. B. Saatkrähen sind. Und für diese "krächzen Raben(-vögel)" eben.

Comment: @tofro Ja so ist es, ich bin ziemlich sicher. Auf schwedisch heißt Krähe "kråka" und auf englisch ja "crow" . Alle diese Wörter haben einen gemeinsamen Stamm, der über das Lateinische "corax" äußerst lautimitierend ist. Quelle: http://www.saob.se/in-english/  Es  ist interessant dass wir hier in Schweden von "krähenvögel" und nicht von rabenvögel" reden, wenn wir die ganze Familie meinen

Comment: @IQV, möglich. Ich hätte Krähe für den Überbegriff gehalten, aber das habe ich vielleicht nur falsch aus dem Englischen übernommen.

Comment: In der Welt, in der ich lebe, unterscheidet der Alltagsbürger sehr wohl zwischen "Raben" und "Krähen". Es ist ihm dabei egal, dass der Biologe beide zu den Rabenvögeln zählen würde, wie vermutlich auch die Dohle. "Kuck mal, der Rabe da!" - "Ach was, das ist doch bloß 'ne Krähe".

Comment: Ich habe mal bei den engl. Kollegen angefragt: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380935/why-does-a-rooster-crow-but-a-crow-caws

Comment: Nur aus neugierde, was tut der Kuckuck? Schreit er?

Comment: @Beta Er *ruft*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ernst Wasserziehers ethymologischem Lexikon "Woher?" Neunte Auflage 1934, Ferd. Dümmlers Verlag, Berlin/Bonn ist folgendes über "krähen" zu lesen:

> **krähen** althochdeutsch *krãen*, angelsachsisch *crawan*, engl *crow*, nicht nur vom Hahn, sondern auch von der **Krähe** (f) eigentlich die Krähende, urverwandt mit litauisch *groti*,
>   altbulgarisch *grajati* (krächzen); griechisch *krozo*, lat. *crocio*:
>   althochdeutsch *hruoh* (Krähe);

Also hat man schon damals darüber gestritten ob nur der Hahn oder auch die Krähe kräht. Jedenfalls damals haben die Verfasser es für richtig angesehen, dass die Krähe kräht. Das kann sich ja aber mit der Zeit verändert haben

Answer (score 3):

**Krähen krähen.**
Daher ist die Frage, warum sie es nicht tun, sinnlos.

Zitat aus dem Eintrag zum Verb [»krähen« auf Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kr%C3%A4hen)

> Bedeutungen:
>    [**1**] den typischen Tierlaut einer Krähe machen
>    [**2**] den typischen Tierlaut eines Hahnes machen
>
> Beispiele:
>    [**1**] Die Krähe kräht.
>    [**2**] Der Hahn kräht auf dem Mist.

Andere Quelle: DUDEN - Das Herkunfswörterbuch (3. Auflage) Seite 448:

> **Krähe:** Die Krähe ist nach ihrem heiseren Geschrei als »Krächzerin« benannt. *[Die an dieser Stelle aufgezählten Formen]* gehören zu der unter *krähen* behandelten Lautnachahmung.

Im gleich drunter stehenden Eintrag zum Verb *krähen* steht, dass das Wort aus der Nachahmung eines Lautes entstanden ist, uns dass neben dem englischen »crow« und den deutschen Wörtern »krähen« und »Krähe« auch »Kranich«, »krachen«, »krächzen«, »kreischen« und »kreißen« derselben lautmalerischen Wurzel entstammen.

Comment: Ich befürchte, dein Wiktionary-Verweis ist Unsinn. Krähen *krähen* definitiv nicht. Zumindest da, wo ich deutsch spreche, tun das nur Hähne.

Comment: ...und zumindestens der Online-Duden ist da mit mir einig.

Comment: Folgt man auf der genannten Wiktionary-Seite dem Link zur [Krähe](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kr%C3%A4he) steht dort als charakteristische Wortkombination "Die Krähe krächzt." Und folgt man hier dem Link zu [krächzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kr%C3%A4chzen) bekommt man als Bedeutung "den Laut des Raben oder einer Krähe machen". Also hat Hubert mit seiner Kernaussage schon Recht, dass die Frage gegenstandslos ist, weil deren Grundannahme ("Für die Krähen bleibt nichts übrig") nicht zutrifft.

Comment: Ich denke, die gemeinsame Verwendung von "krähen" und "Krähen" kommt vielen Beiträgern hier nur deshalb unbekannt vor, weil eben überhaupt selten einmal über Lautäußerungen von Krähen gesprochen wird. Warum sollte man auch? Der Hahn, der kräht, ist dagegen ein recht präsentes Element dörflicher Alltagskultur und ländlichen Tagesablaufs (da wo's halt noch Hähne gibt), und darum wird öfter drüber gesprochen. *Wenn* man aber über die Lautäußerungen von Krähen spräche, nähme man doch vielleicht auch "krähen" dafür her.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Also da, wo ich lebe, gibt es wesentlich mehr Krähen als Hähne. Trotzdem krähen bei uns nur die Letzteren (und, natürlich, die Babys)

Comment: Babys "krähen"?!?

Comment: @Gerhard Wenn du das fragen musst, hast do wohl noch keins gehabt... "Früh kräht in der Wiege, was später eine kluge Frau werden wird." *Die Zeit, 11.8.67*, oder frag' mal Google nach "kräht vor Vergnügen"

Comment: @tofro: bei uns würde das wohl nur fragende Blicke ernten...  Babys "kreischen" (oder "schreien") bei uns in der Gegend.  Ist wohl regional bedingt...

Answer (score 0):

Krähen bedeutet ursprünglich Geschrei (von Vögeln). Das tun die Krähen als auch der Hahn recht ordentlich. Beim Hahn hat sich das erhalten in "krähen", für die Krähen selbst ist es nur im Namen erhalten geblieben, aber für das Tiergeräusch hat sich das Krächzen dagegen im Nachhinein stattdessen durchgesetzt, denn es ist jünger als krähen (siehe dazu auch [hier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380935/why-does-a-rooster-crow-but-a-crow-caws)).

---

siehe Quelle: Grimms Deutsches Wörterbuch

**krächzen** , ... ein intensivum zu krachen, wie krächsen, mit dem es sich leicht mischt (s. dort). ahd. mhd. nicht belegt, es wäre ahd. chrachizan. dafür erscheint ablautend ahd. croccizan, mhd. krochzen (s. DWB kröchzen), von denen das erste im stammauslaut zu kräcken, kräcksen stimmt. ...
**1)** von thieren.
**a)** von raben, krähen, eulen u. dgl.: der traurige krächzende nachtrabe.

"**krähen** , vom gesang des hahns u. ä.
**I.** Formen und verwandtschaft. 
... 
**3)** die verwandtschaft. 
**a)** vor allem tritt hervor die thatsache, dasz krähen in der form mit krähe zusammengeht, wie in der schlieszlichen nhd. festsetzung, so fast in allen seinen schwankungen und wandelungen vorher, bis in unsere vorzeit zurück. man vergleiche nur z. b. ags. crâwan mit crâwe, nd. kreien mit kreie, mhd. kræwen mit krâwe, alem. kräyen im 16. jh. mit kräy ebend., nnl. kraajen mit kraai, bair. krânen mit krân krähe. das sprachgefühl hat also beide entschieden zusammen gehalten, und wie diesz bestätigt dasz die krähe vom geschrei benannt ist, ebenso dasz krähen urspr. nicht auf den hahn beschränkt sein konnte, wie sich denn das unter II, 2 zeigt, ganz entschieden aber unter II, 3. so wird es kein zufall sein, dasz auch das goth. wort für krähen, hrûkjan, ganz nahe zusammentrifft mit einem namen der krähe, ahd. hruoch, ags. hrôc (s. unter krähe sp. 1968 unten).

**II.** Bedeutung.
**1)** vom hahne, wie es jetzt fast allein gilt (s. aber 2. 3).
**a)** im gewöhnlichen sinne, der hahn kräht
..."